# I have one radio button and inputfield in lightning

Tags: javascript, radio-button

[image]

I have one radio button and one input-field..I am trying to achieve something like.if i click on the radio button , the input field should get active and value of that input-field should come automatically..If the radio button is not selected ..the field should be available but it should be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

Component:

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
                                                    {'label': 'Codes', 'value': '1'},
                                                    {'label': 'Mappings', 'value': '2'}
                                                    ]"/>
<aura:attribute name="radioValue" type="Integer" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="textValue" type="String" default=""/>
<lightning:radioGroup
                      aura:id="radioGrp"
                      name="radioButtonGroup"
                      label="Data to Export"
                      options="{! v.options }"
                      value="{! v.radioValue }"
                      onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
                      />
<ui:inputText aura:id="file" label="Export File Name" disabled="true" value="{!v.textValue}"/>
```

Controller:

```
handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var val = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    console.log('val',val);
    if(val) {
        var inputFile = component.find("file");
        inputFile.set("v.disabled",false);
        inputFile.set("v.value","Value to be Set Dynamically");
    }
}
```

Using radioGroup will be suitable for your case.And having separate attributes will be make it reusable wherever you need.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your requirement in my developer org. Please add below mentioned code to any component and add test it.

**.cmp file >**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
<aura:attribute name="myText" type="string" default=""/>

<ui:inputText aura:id='textField' label="Export File name" value="" disabled='true'/>    
<ui:inputRadio label='Date To Export' change='{!c.onRadio}' />
```

make sure to close aura:component at the end, as i am not able to include in the above mentioned code.

**.controllerjs file >**
enter the below mentioned code in the client side js file

```
({
onRadio: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.find("textField").set("v.value","Automated Text appeared here!"); 
    cmp.find("textField").set("v.disabled",'false');
},})
```

so whenever you click on the radio button input text has been update and the field is editable.

[image]

[image]